# How to open a popup, detect its closure, and redirect the main window

Tags: javascript, popup

What I would like to achieve is very very similar to what [Play Spotify](https://play.spotify.com/browse) does.

If you try to log into Spotify with Facebook here is what happens and what I would like to replicate:

1. You click on the Facebook button
2. A popup opens
3. You insert your credentials
4. If you succeed, the popup closes
5. The main window gets redirected

The only differences are that, first, the page I want to open is different from the facebook one, and second is that, in my case, when the popups closes I want to read its last `location.href` and then redirect my main page to this link.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass a return URL to your own page to the Facebook login flow.
2. In that page, use `window.opener` to get the `window` object (and global scope) of your original page.
3. Use that to call a function in the original page to do whatever you want.